# ArcGIS Collector for Windows 10 Desktop Issue

Tags: feature-service, arcgis-collector

I've got a few collector apps and they all seem to work fine on Android and iOS devices, but I can never get them to load into the desktop Collector for ArcGIS. Every time I get this error on the layer:

**Invalid SpatialReference: The Wkid or VerticalWkid value is invalid**

I can still for some reason add new features. As soon as I finish adding it, it disappears from the map though.

Notes:

- These Collector feature layers are stored on my ArcServer, from an SDE that is versioned and tracking edits.
- I've got points lines and polygons across various SDEs and apps, tried a lot of other workarounds, but nothing is working.
- Layers are in WGS84 and CVGD2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an error within the ArcGIS Collector App. Its since been fixed if you try is again.